# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки появлялся введённый пользователем текст

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть тег input type=text, куда пользователь вводит любой текст, и при нажатии input=button с OnClick этот текст должен появится в ранее поставленном font. Как это максимально кратко реализовать через скрипт?

```
<form>
<input type=text> // куда вводить текст 
<input type=button OnClick="ClickFunction1()" value=Отправить> //кнопка для отправки текста
</form>
<font id=font1></font> // место где должен появится текст
<script>
function ClickFunction1() {
getElementById("font1"). innerHTML = ""; //и после = по сути нужно указать путь/имя/айди(?) до input=text
</script>
```

Comment: Покажите, как это реализовано у вас и что значит "Максимально кратко"? Кратко и читабельно это разные вещи

Comment: У меня это никак не реализовано, тк я даже не знаю как это сделать. Ну на счёт кратко я имел ввиду максимально просто, тк я не очень понимаю js

Comment: Откуда ты откапал этот тег `font`... Он же древнее мамонтов... Не используй его, вообще забудь про него

Answer (score 0):

Вроде так.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let inputValue = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
  let font = document.getElementById("font1");
  font.innerHTML = inputValue;
});
```

```html
<form>
<input type=text>
<input type=button value=Отправить>
</form>
<div id=font1></div>
```

Comment: нельзя в html разметке писать обработчик событий, типа не правильно это, лучше использовать addEventListener

Comment: А почему нельзя и кто сказал, что это не правильно?

Comment: @Air можно, но не желательно. Гораздо легче просто посмотреть в JS и понять где начинается функция, чем искать, а где же эта функция - ClickFunction1() находится? АААА она в HTML, ну буду искать где же обработчик этот в HTML. Ну я думаю вы уловили смысл)). Для самого разработчика это кажется быстро, взял прописал обработчик событий и написал функцию, а для тех, кто будет после вас дорабатывать или вы сами спустя год к вам обращаются с просьбой доработать и вы такой смотрите и думаете - ЭТО Я что ли делал, да не может быть)).

Answer (score 0):

> Как это максимально кратко реализовать через скрипт?

Пробую максимально кратко...

```js
const a = document.querySelectorAll('input')
a[1].addEventListener('click', _ => {
  font1.textContent = a[0].value
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type=text /> 
  <input type=button value=Отправить />
</form>
<font id=font1></font>
```